InputNumber Antd doesn't allow null value when using with react-hook-form
So, this has been bugging me for quite some time. Here is my piece of code:
<InputNumber
                    {...register(ticketsPath, {
                        valueAsNumber: true,
                        min: 1,
                    })}
                    placeholder="1"
                    className={clsx(styles.inputNumber, {
                        [styles.error]: !isNullish(index)
                            ? errors[basePath]?.[index]?.tickets
                            : errors[basePath]?.tickets,
                    })}
                    value={watch(ticketsPath)}
                    onChange={(value) => {
                        assertNumber(value);
                        setValue(ticketsPath, value);
                        trigger(ticketsPath);
                    }}
                />

I'm using Antdv4 and react-hook-form. My problem is that if I leave this input empty, it will return NaN, and I want it to return null. I have put console.logs in my onChange function, and it logs null when for example I delete value (which is expected), but I guess that after submiting my form, valueAsNumber sees that value as not a number, and assignees it NaN. What is a good, neat workaround this?
I have tried removing valueAsNumber (but then I get strings in my input, which is not a thing I want). Also tried many things in my onChange function but that's not the source of the problem, since null will always be translated to NaN on submit.
